# Chrome show https invalid, but says that the certification is valid

Tags: ssl

Chrome show https invalid, but says that the certification is valid

[image]

[image]
What is the problem with the certificate?

Comment: A side note: A payment provider with a let's encrypt certificate? That smells like phishing.

Comment: Check the developer console (F12). Most probably some resource (image,js, css) is loaded via http.

Comment: What do you see when you click on the "Not Secure" warning to the left of the URL?

Answer (score 3):

The URL you are visiting is `www.paykey.com`. The certificate is issued to `paykey.com`. The certificate does not contain `www.paykey.com` in the Subject Alternative Name field.

Therefore, there is no match. Strict browsers will raise an error in this case.

Comment: Letsencrypt is an awesome, free & opensource ssl provider. But you have to pay for wildcard ssl (*.domain.com).

Here, the certificate issued for www.paykey.com & you are browsing paykey.com with that certificate.

Either need to get free letsencrypt cert for www.paykey.com + paykey.com or
purchase *.paykey.com

OR
use www.paykey.com and redirect all requests from paykey.com to www.paykey.com

Comment: This is a wrong answer, this happens with both domains - see updated question

Comment: @EliaWeiss The certificate SAN field does not contain www.paykey.com, so strict browsers will still raise an error when visiting that domain. See the "Common Name Support Removed" section here: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/security-changes-in-chrome-58/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a chrome extension

[image]